Make start day of the week as monday for a specific table under SQL Server
I want to make Monday as the start day of the week for a specific table. I have searched but couldn't find a proper solution. @@datefirst will be useful for the current session but my task is to set the startday for a table
Table with date column and specifying start day as Monday instead of Sunday

Mysql is a totally different product to SQL server - please correct your tags

"I want to make Monday as the start day of the week for a specific table" You mean like having a column where Monday is 1 instead of 2 or something? I suggest a Calendar table.

Like @thomA stated, are you talking about setting a sequence like 1, 2 etc...  assigned to days of the week?  When building your table you could set logic in the build to create a separate column that assigned a numerical value to the days of the week.
